# Splunk: docker-compose starts but web GUI is not available

Tags: docker, docker-compose, splunk

I have a docker-compose.yml to run **splunk** and **splunkforwarder** containers.

This docker-compose start OK, but when I try to access http://localhost:8000, a got error: This site can’t be reached.

My current system is **Linux Ubuntu**.

BTW: I have anothers docker containers working perfect in my system.

Please see my docker-compose below:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  splunk:
    image: splunk/splunk
    container_name: splunk
    environment:
      - SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license
      - SPLUNK_USER=root
      - SPLUNK_PASSWORD=Te0k324ja#
      - SPLUNK_ENABLE_LISTEN=9997
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  splunkforwarder:
    image: splunk/universalforwarder:latest
    container_name: splunkforwarder
    environment:
      - SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license --answer-yes
      - SPLUNK_FORWARD_SERVER=splunk:9997
      - SPLUNK_USER=root
      - SPLUNK_PASSWORD=Te0k324ja#
      - SPLUNK_ADD=monitor /logs
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - splunk
    volumes:
      - log_volume:/logs

volumes:
  log_volume:
```

---

EDIT:
After around 10 minutes the splunks begins to listen at port 8000. Could someone test my docker-compose file, too see if works at another system?

In the splunk GUI I got the following RED alert:

[Screenshot of the splunk alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYQfE.png)IOWait
Root Cause(s):
System iowait reached red threshold of 3
Maximum per-cpu iowait reached red threshold of 10
Sum of 3 highest per-cpu iowaits reached red threshold of 15

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like the server isn't running if you can't curl from localhost within the container. Can you check the logs of the container and see if it's running properly?

Answer (score 1):

Bash into the container as the splunk user and head to the `opt/splunk/etc/system/local/web.conf` for port settings

Then run `./splunk` show web port or run `.splunk` set web port

I had similar issues with docker compose and splunk setting the port as default.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access localhost:8000, but the only port you are exposing is

`- 3001:8000`

so at very least you should try localhost:3001 oh host computer.

If that doesn't work do

`docker-compose exec splunk bash`

and try `curl -XGET http://localhost:8000` to se if splunk actually works with in container.

Comment: Good observation. I fixed the 8000:8000, but the problem persists. The curl command into container returned curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused

Comment: that would mean that splunk doesn't really respond to get requests.
splunk documentation doesn't say you need specify `SPLUNK_ENABLE_LISTEN`, does that changes the port it listens for?
here is doc, try specifying only what is shows in example of `docker run` command:
`https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/splunk/#documentation`